# Starting from the beginning of a sequence, I need to delete any instance that is less than 30 days from the next instance

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'll start with my dataset:

```
patient_id                                event_description     
            A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-01-15
            A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-02-10
            A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-04-20
            A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-06-02
            B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-08-15
            B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-08-20
            B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-09-20
            B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-10-30
            C                                             DiagnosisA          2016-10-15
            C                                             DiagnosisA          2016-11-20
            C                                             DiagnosisA          2016-11-25
            C                                             DiagnosisA          2016-12-30
```

Essentially, I need to:

- calculate the difference between 1st instance of an `event_description` and the 2nd and see if the difference is less than or greater than 30. If it is less than thirty, I will get rid of that instance.
- This will need to be done for every instance for each `event_description` and `patient_id`

The final sample dataset would like like:

```
patient_id                                event_description     
            A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-01-15
            A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-04-20
            A                                             DiagnosisA          2016-06-02
            B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-08-15
            B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-09-20
            B                                             DiagnosisA          2016-10-30
            C                                             DiagnosisA          2016-10-15
            C                                             DiagnosisA          2016-11-20
            C                                             DiagnosisA          2016-12-30
```

Comment: Please share the code you have so far. Are you asking for the entire solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `groupby` and `diff`

Notice: change your date to datetime `df.value=pd.to_datetime(df.value)`

```
df[~df.groupby('patient_id').value.diff().dt.days.lt(30)]
Out[754]: 
   patient_id event_description      value
0           A        DiagnosisA 2016-01-15
2           A        DiagnosisA 2016-04-20
3           A        DiagnosisA 2016-06-02
4           B        DiagnosisA 2016-08-15
6           B        DiagnosisA 2016-09-20
7           B        DiagnosisA 2016-10-30
8           C        DiagnosisA 2016-10-15
9           C        DiagnosisA 2016-11-20
11          C        DiagnosisA 2016-12-30
```

Data input

```
df
Out[755]: 
   patient_id event_description      value
0           A        DiagnosisA 2016-01-15
1           A        DiagnosisA 2016-02-10
2           A        DiagnosisA 2016-04-20
3           A        DiagnosisA 2016-06-02
4           B        DiagnosisA 2016-08-15
5           B        DiagnosisA 2016-08-20
6           B        DiagnosisA 2016-09-20
7           B        DiagnosisA 2016-10-30
8           C        DiagnosisA 2016-10-15
9           C        DiagnosisA 2016-11-20
10          C        DiagnosisA 2016-11-25
11          C        DiagnosisA 2016-12-30
```

Comment: @madsthaks yw have a nice day